# Is there a way to run Valgrind directly on Rspec tests?

Tags: c, ruby, rspec, valgrind

I am using Valgrind, and it is pretty amazing.  Right now I'm basically setting up unique ruby files that call the code that I want Valgrind to test.  But it'd be nice if I could just run Valgrind on my rspec tests directly, right now when I try I get this error:

```
.../rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': 
Could not find RubyGem rspec-core (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Comment: Is rspec-core listed when you do `gem list`?